# Make Token In Python

Tags: python, token

I want to make random token from this token :

`73dfad3e124964b28e5d1a45c931f3c5f44921ca`

How can i make token from that token like this :

```
73dfad3e124964b28e5d1a45c931f3c5f44921cb
73dfad3e124964b28e5d1a45c931f3c5f44921cc
73dfad3e124964b28e5d1a45c931f3c5f44921cd
Etc
```

Comment: You want to make a random token or you want to change the existing token by adding to it?  A little confused what you are looking to try accomplish.

Comment: Looks like OP wants to increment the token - `...ca` → `...cb` → `...cc` etc

Comment: Please specify how you are generating new tokens? What is the criteria?

Comment: Having incrementing tokens really defeats the security of tokens. They should be at least pseudo random.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what token you want to generate.
You can simply do this way;

```
import secrets
secrets.token_hex(16)
```